# Can I extend postgres's method for casting strings to UUIDs?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

Postgres allows you to cast text types to uuids as per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) using the following syntax:

```sql
select 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-7cc0ce491b22' :: uuid;
```

However, I frequently use a shorter base64 representation (or even base62) of a UUID in places such as URL where it is nicer to be more concise, such as:

> mydomain.com/packages/krAeMd84SayIc27ugvi9VQ/

But I can't copy and paste that into a database to find the underlying database row, because it is not the hex format postgres expects.

Is there a way I can extend the standard cast mechanism in postgres to allow me to do either of:

```sql
select 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-7cc0ce491b22' :: uuid;
-- or
select 'krAeMd84SayIc27ugvi9VQ' :: uuid;
```

?

Comment: You can, sort of, but you're not going to like how. 

Basically it boils down to either adding a new type or extending/overriding the existing type.   I'll try to add a more detailed answer if I get a moment.  But in the interests of solving your problem rather than just answering your question, I suspect a better route for you to go would be to create a custom function that transforms the B64 into the expanded hex format and just cast that.

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-createtype.html and linked chapters for the type-based solution.

Comment: For the function-based solution, it's probably worth noting that both `DECODE` and `ENCODE` already exist in postgresql, so you could just use those directly.

Comment: Yeah, I could use functions explicitly, but I'm not the only person who might want to use it within my company, and then they'd all have to remember the function to call. It would be hugely more convenient if they don't have to change the way they are used to making queries, but can just use the base6n strings directly without converting to hex first.

Comment: then check out the first solution.  You're not going to like it, lol, but it should be mostly boilerplate since you can piggy-back off of the existing uuid type (and the underlying c functions that make it work) as well as the existing decode function.

Comment: Note too that you can still provide a consistent interface with a function-based approach.  Just make your function accept both types of strings and only run decode if the string happens to be B64.  Might not work for you, but putting it here for others who come here.

Comment: I recommend that you do not use a type cast, but write a database function that converts your string representation to something that `uuid`'s type input function understands.